# How to make dropdown <a> and <li> to have same width

Tags: html, css

I have created a dropdown as below

```
 <ul id="drop-nav">   
  <li>
    <a href="#">Web Design</a>        
  <ul>         
  <li> <a href="#">HTML</a></li>          
  <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>          
  <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>        
</ul>      
</li>    
</ul>
```

here i want dropdown name [here web design] and dropdown list to have same width. So if i change 'Javacript' to 'I want to learn Javascript' in list then it should change Web design width also. Now both are independent. I dont want to set width:100% , i want to change size based on content length. Now both are changing independently . I want both to change at same time.

Below is the plunker code.Please help me to do this

https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: Looks like you added the wrong link

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to change the size of the  (Web Design) element using just CSS, because it is a "sibling" of the other elements that you want to be dynamic. If you add display: inline-block to the first li element which is a parent of the others, then that element will adjust to the width of the other  elements.

If you really needed to, you could use JavaScript to adjust the width of the Web Design  tag when the other fields are changed.